# Как совместить эти три запроса (SQL)?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, phpmyadmin

Как совместить эти запросы в один?

```
INSERT INTO db (name,link) VALUES ('%name%','%link%') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE link = '%link%'
UPDATE db SET date = concat(date, '%date%|');
UPDATE db SET f = concat(f, '%price%|');
```

Comment: первое с вторыми двумя никак. MySQL не может выполнять более одного действия за раз. Второе и тертье предложение собираются в одно, условия в SET просто перечисляются через запятую. Обратите внимание - данные update поменяют абсолютно все записи в таблице

Comment: Вот именно, что меняет абсолютно весь столбец. А все должно происходить в одной вставке, тоесть в одной строке :( Выходит так что первый запрос отрабатывает локально, а остальные два глобально.

Comment: Разумеется, если вам надо что бы update менял конкретные строки вы должны указать какие именно строки менять в предложении where

Comment: поможете? Google есть и картина есть, но привык что стак дает то что нужно.

Comment: А если вам надо что бы эти изменения происходили именно над той строкой, которую не удалось вставить из за того, что она есть надо просто дописать что еще менять через запятую `.... on duplicate key update link=x, date=y, f=z` А еще обращаю ваше внимание, что хранение какиз либо значений в одном поле через разделитель, практически самое ужасное, что можно сделать с БД. про нормальную работу с такой БД можно забыть. Все множественные значения должны выноситься в отдельные таблицы, связанные с данной...

Comment: см. "Нормальная форма" https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0

Comment: Стак не сможет вам дать то что вам нужно, если вы не скажете в вопросе, что именно требуется сделать

Comment: Мне потом эти данные грузить в Таблуи для аналитики. Там есть разделители. Знаю что не по правильному. Пошел пробовать Ваш вариант...

Comment: все равно, денные лучше положить правильно. если на выходе они понадобятся в таком виде, то их и надо собрать в требуемый вид при выдачи (например с помощью group_concat)